# Magento Connect Manager - Error #619 security: script is world-writable

Tags: magento

i have a curious issue. When i start the connect manager i see a white window with the following error message: svwrap $Revision: 1.36 $
Error #619 security: script is world-writable
Does anyone have an idea what could be? I know what "world-writable" means but what file it might be? Thanks for an answer. Hermann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd contact your hosting company this.  This message isn't generated by Magento, it's generated by a program your web hosting company has installed to scan for world writable scripts.

Also, you may want to consider a different web-host if you need to use Magento Connect's web UI.  This feature requires the Magento web server user have write access to the Magento installation to download and update files.  It sounds like your hosting company may not be down with that.

All that said, my guess is it's, at minimum, the `downloader/index.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I have corrected the permissions (644) of the [downloader/index.php] now it works fine as before.